# tree entity with two object same type child and parent

Tags: c#, ef-core-5.0

I have a tree class which contains two properties with the same type of that class. What happened is when added to the database using ef core 5 it adds the value for only one property depending on relationship configuration in model builder.

```
public class UnitOfProduct 
{
       public UnitOfProduct()
    {
    }
    public UnitOfProduct(UnitOfProduct parentUnitOfProduct)
    {
        ChildUnitOfProduct = parentUnitOfProduct;
    }
    
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }

    public long? ChildUnitOfProductId { get; set; }
    public UnitOfProduct ChildUnitOfProduct { get; set; }

    public decimal ChildUnitContentOfProduct { get; set; }

    public long? ParentUnitOfProductId { get; set; }
    public UnitOfProduct ParentUnitOfProduct { get; set; }
}




  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UnitOfProduct>()
            .HasOne(b => b.ChildUnitOfProduct)
            .WithOne(i => i.ParentUnitOfProduct)
            .HasForeignKey<UnitOfProduct>(i=>i.ParentUnitOfProductId);

     
    }


    public async Task<UnitOfProduct> CreateFullProduct(FullProduct fullProduct)
    {
        UnitOfProduct parentUnitOfProduct = null;

        UnitOfProduct childUnitOfProduct = null;
        foreach (var unitOfProductBuilder in fullProduct.UnitOfProductBuilders)
        {
            if (parentUnitOfProduct == null)
            {
                parentUnitOfProduct = new UnitOfProduct(null)
                {
                    Product = fullProduct.Product,
                    ChildUnitContentOfProduct = unitOfProductBuilder.ChildContent,
                    UnitId = unitOfProductBuilder.UnitId
                };
            }


            else
            {
                childUnitOfProduct = new UnitOfProduct(parentUnitOfProduct)
                {
                    Product = fullProduct.Product,
                    ChildUnitContentOfProduct = unitOfProductBuilder.ChildContent,
                    UnitId = unitOfProductBuilder.UnitId
                };
                parentUnitOfProduct = childUnitOfProduct;
            }
        }


        await _repositoryWrapper.UnitOfProductRepository.Add(
            childUnitOfProduct
        );

        return parentUnitOfProduct;
    }
```

the result in unitOfProducts table is :

| Id | ChildUnitOfProductId | ParentUnitOfProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | null | null |
| 25 | null | 24 |
| 26 | null | 25 |

expected to be :

| Id | ChildUnitOfProductId | ParentUnitOfProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 25 | null |
| 25 | 26 | 24 |
| 26 | null | 25 |

what

Comment: First thing I see weird is: `ChildUnitOfProduct = parentUnitOfProduct;` -> why is a parent assigned to a child? Is the parameter name wrong or the assignment wrong?